# How to give users a link to get profile from site?

Tags: asp.net

Some web sites, like StackOverflow, about.me etc... give their user a link that could be placed on any website/weblogs to show off user profile or any kind of data, like this (on StackOverFlow.com flair:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/***/***">
<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/***.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for USERNAME at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for UserNAME at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
</a>
```

and user can see a little bit of their own profile.
In short, how it is implement?

**EDIT**: Should I use the Web Service?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you using ASP.NET Membership, is very easy way to do this. 
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Something like this gives you a username of currently logged user. In Web Forms put the hyperlink on master page and dynamically set href and link text in code behind. In MVC Razor you can put it on layout page.

In case of your own membership system, then checking for id from session, and get the user info of it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example how to make dynamic link to profile of active user with standard ASP.NET membership. I'm talking about ASP.NET WebForms.

1. Create custom ASP.NET control UserProfileLink.ascx with similar content

   ```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="Link" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# Url %>" Text="<%# UserName %>" />
   ```
2. In code behind for this control define 2 properties:

   ```
   public string UserName
   {
       get
       {
           return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
       }
   }

   public string Url
   {
       get
       {
           MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
           Debug.Assert(user != null);

           return string.Format("~/users/{0}/", (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In code behind for this control override OnLoad:

   ```
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   {
       Link.DataBind();

       base.OnLoad(e);
   }
   ```
4. On your page use UserProfileLink control within LoginView control:

   ```
   <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
      <AnonymousTemplate>
      ..
      </AnonymousTemplate>
      <LoggedInTemplate>
          <uc:UserProfileLink ID="UserProfileLink" runat="server" />
          ...
      </LoggedInTemplate>
   </asp:LoginView>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it is NOT some thing like ,for example, stackoverflow flair.

Comment: This solution shows how to put link based on information about current user. If you need additional information (not just link to user profile) - you can scale it easily - get information from your own database model based by current user id. You also may look at source code of Orchard (http://orchardproject.net/) or BlogEngine.Net (http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) to get more ideas how to implement this.